# Using a different source for a PHP Extension

Tags: php, imagemagick

I need to use `imagick` PHP extension for image manipulation. Before I installed this extension, I also installed ImageMagick on the machine using `sudo apt install imagemagick`. Turns out, this version is outdated (because it's not supporting HEIC image format). So I installed ImageMagick from the source, which installed as `magick` package. But the PHP's imagick extension is still working with earlier outdated `imagemagick`.

How do I tell PHP's imagick extension to use the latest `magick` package I installed from source?

Comment: I guess if you want to use PHP's with your own compiled version of imagmagick, you need to also manually compiled the PHP's module with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using distro's own PHP imagick module, it will be impossible to use your own ImageMagick copy.

There are 2 ways to use your own ImageMagick:

1. Compile your own PHP from source with the specified ImageMagick copy.
2. Use [ImageMagick with command line](https://imagemagick.org/script/magick.php) through proc_open or similar function calls.

I guess the second option would be much easier and more flexible than to compile the whole PHP. It's best to keep using distro's PHP, with all the security updates and patches delivered to you automatically, than to maintain your own binary.

Answer (score 0):

To build the imagick PECL extension from source based on a non-standard ImageMagick installation directory you need to specify the directory using [the `--with-imagick` argument](https://github.com/Imagick/imagick/blob/28f27044e435a2b203e32675e942eb8de620ee58/config.m4#L2) of the extension's `configure` script.

However, the `pecl` command provides more user-friendly way to install PECL extensions. Here is how you can install both the ImageMagick package and the imagick PECL extension:

1. Install ImageMagick:

```bash
# Prepare target directory.
# !!!
# !!! Warning: Replace this path with whatever path you prefer on your system.
# !!!
target_dir="/home/johndoe/usr/lib/imagemagick"

mkdir -p "$target_dir"

git clone https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick.git ImageMagick-7.1.1
cd ImageMagick-7.1.1
./configure --prefix="$target_dir"
make
make install
```

2. Install the PECL extension:

```bash
sudo pecl install imagick
```

The command will ask to provide a path to the ImageMagick installation directory. Paste the ImageMagick installation directory here (replace `/home/johndoe/usr/lib/imagemagick` with your path):

```
Please provide the prefix of ImageMagick installation [autodetect] : /home/johndoe/usr/lib/imagemagick
```

Then add `extension=imagick.so` to php.ini *or* run PHP CLI with `-d 'extension=imagick.so'` arguments, e.g.:

```bash
$ php -d 'extension=imagick.so' -m | grep imagick
imagick
```